# Print summary of frequency of one column that requires two other columns in order to figure out?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I had other issues that I resolved but this problem here has set me back a little bit.

I have the following columns (there's 50,000 total data in my actual file):

```
Area        Date        SpeedOver        Risk     Accident   
Wendly    8/8/2010          15            L          No
Wendly    2/9/2010          35            L          Yes
Reet      1/5/2010          65            M          Yes
Reet      9/11/2010         10            M          Yes
Sarall    14/3/2010         18            M          No
Sarall    7/6/2010          23            H          No
Sarall    23/6/2014         25            H          Yes
```

I am trying to print the top 3 locations based on accidents in the year of 2010. So the output should be:

```
Reet
Wendly
Sarall
```

```
top_loc_accident = df[(df.index.year==2010)]['Accident'].nlargest(n=3)

print(top_loc_accident)
```

But the above code prints the date itself and the accidents, not the actual location name, so I have it 50% correct but it's a bit confusing currently.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to aggregate the number of accidents:

```
# select rows of 2010
# the original method can be used here
m1 = df['Date'].str.endswith('2010')
# m1 = df.index.year==2010

# identify rows with accidents
m2 = df['Accident'].eq('Yes')

# count the accidents of 2010
# keep the top 3
m2[m1].groupby(df['Area']).sum().nlargest(3)
```

Output:

```
Area
Reet      2
Wendly    1
Sarall    0
Name: Accident, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I didn't realize I was way off with my attempt at answering my own question. But your answer helped, thanks